# Espresso-web check web element doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, webview, android-espresso

I'm using espresso-web to test a `webview` in my android app. I want to test that an element doesn't exist. How can this be done?

**Background:** We have a web service that delivers pages to our mobile website as well as to the `webview` in the android app. Since the android app has it's own `actionbar`, we don't want to display the header in that is displayed in the page when it's opened in the browser on a mobile device.

For other non-`webviews`, I've been able to use the following code that tests that native elements aren't displayed.

```
ViewInteraction logoutView = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.account_logout), withText("logout"), isDisplayed()));

logoutView.check(doesNotExist());
```

I was hoping something similar to the following would work

```
Web.WebInteraction<Void> mobileWebHeader =  onWebView().   
    withElement(findElement(Locator.TAG_NAME, "header"));
mobileWebHeader.check(doesNotExist());
```

Unfortunately it doesn't and I haven't found any alternatives.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a better solution than using try/catch in this case:

```
try {
    onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.TAG_NAME, "header"));
} catch (RuntimeException notExist) {
    //good!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIAutomator for this. Say you want to wait until a checkbox is displayed, and then see if its checked. You can do this:

```
    // Get the UIAutomator device object
    UiDevice uiDevice =
            UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    // Get your specific element 
    UiObject checkbox = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .instance(0)
            .className(CheckBox.class));
    // Wait till it exists with whatever time you want
    if(checkbox.waitForExists(1000)) {
       // Do whatever you want with it 
        try {

            if(!checkbox.isChecked())
                onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled()
                        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "checkboxTOS")) 
                        .perform(webClick()); // Similar to perform(click())

        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {}

    }
```

You can replace

> CheckBox.class

with whatever you want. Just take a [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) screenshot of the page you want to use, and see what type it gives to whatever you're looking for.

Source: https://medium.com/azimolabs/android-webview-automation-testing-6311df8fe42e